# How to change background colour using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a button that can change the background colour using Vuejs2. It should change 2 different colours after every click using If-else. Idk why it's not working.
Should i use Vue if-else statement and @click ?
**HTML**

```
<div id ="app"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bgbutton {
  background-color: #D8DFE5;
  border: none;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.bgbutton:hover {
  border-color: #dadce0;
  color: #A52A2A;
}

.button-16:focus {
  border-color: #4285f4;
  outline: none;
}
body {
  font: Arial , sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(#2d8dcb, #F0FFFF); 
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
 var test2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{},
  methods: {
    
    changebg: function(){
const btn = document.getElementById('bgbtn');
const backgroundColor = btn.style.background;
if (backgroundColor == 'linear-gradient(#2d8dcb, #F0FFFF)') {
 btn.style.backgroundColor = 'linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5)';
  } else {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'linear-gradient(#2d8dcb, #F0FFFF)';
  }
    }
  },
     template:' <button id= bgbtn class= bgbutton v-on:click = changebg > Change Background colour</button>',
})
```

Comment: Note that Vue 3 is the current version and that Vue 2 reaches "end of life" in 2023.  See: [What's the difference between Vue 2 and Vue 3?](https://vuejs.org/about/faq.html#what-s-the-difference-between-vue-2-and-vue-3)

Comment: I know, I'm in college and they asked to use Vue2. I don't know why they won't update the program

Answer (score 0):

Several issues ...

1. linear-gradient is a `backgroundImage`, not a `backgroundColor`
2. setting `backgroundImage` to `linear-gradient(#2d8dcb, #F0FFFF)` is fine, but when you read it next time, it *may* be `linear-gradient(rgb(45, 141, 203), rgb(240, 255, 255))` ... so your comparison will fail

So, this code seems to do what you want

```js
var test2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  methods: {

    changebg: function(e) {
      const btn = e.originalTarget;
      const toggle = btn.dataset.bg || 0;
      if (toggle === "1" ) {
        btn.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5)';
      } else {
        btn.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(#2d8dcb, #F0FFFF)';
      }
      btn.dataset.bg = 1 - toggle
    }
  },
  template: '<button id="bgbtn" class="bgbutton" @click="changebg" > Change Background colour</button>',
})
```

```css
.bgbutton {
  background-color: #D8DFE5;
  border: none;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.bgbutton:hover {
  border-color: #dadce0;
  color: #A52A2A;
}

.button-16:focus {
  border-color: #4285f4;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(#2d8dcb, #F0FFFF);
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Personally, I use classes if I can for such things

```js
var test2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  methods: {

    changebg: function(e) {
      const btn = e.originalTarget;
      btn.classList.toggle('alt');
    }
  },
  template: '<button id="bgbtn" class="bgbutton" @click="changebg">Change Background colour</button>',
})
```

```css
.bgbutton {
  background-color: #D8DFE5;
  border: none;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#2d8dcb, #F0FFFF)
}

.bgbutton.alt {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}

.bgbutton:hover {
  border-color: #dadce0;
  color: #A52A2A;
}

.button-16:focus {
  border-color: #4285f4;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(#2d8dcb, #F0FFFF);
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```